# Dropdown list in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, c#-4.0

I'm learning ASP.NET MVC and I need to make a gender drop down list it shows (Male , Female) to the user but the selected gender value saved in the SQL Database is (1 for the male , 2 for the Female)

Thank you.

I tried using the `enum` in the Model

public int? Gender { get; set; }

```
 public enum Gender
    {
       Male,Female
    }
```

and this code in the view

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Gender,
            new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(schoolproject1.Models.Gender))),
            "Select Gender")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you are doing well! You can use the following code to find out your user's selection.

Just you should code like this

C# Back-end Model:

```
public int Gender {get; set;}
```

MVC View CsHtml

```
<select name="Gender" class="form-control">
    <option value="1">Male</option>
    <option value="2">Female</option>
 </select>
```

Then you must work and save the value while Back-end is working

```
Data data = new Data();
data.Gender = Gender;
model.Data.Add(data); // Whether Add or Modify
model.SaveChanges();
```